# I cant return a value with system.linq.IQueryable, Is there any way?

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 separate service that each one read data form 2 table.
now in my salPrice service that getting data from salPrice table before getting data I need to get a value from another service which name is sysUser
so I write another method to in sysUser service to get that value and return 
in my salPrice I want to add e condition to check if salprice.GroupCode = sysUser.PosSection

in salPrice service before returning my data I call that method for getting possection form sysUser service and put it in a Var PosSection.
so I write a new method in sysUser but It seems I couldn't return a string and this error appears to me: "cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'"

```
 public  IQueryable<SysUsers> GetCurrentPasSection(int userCode)
 {
    var query = $@"select PosSection from _sysusers where UserCode = {userCode}";
    string query1 = query;
    return query1;
}
```

Comment: query is not linq, it's a string!

Comment: How do you usually read data from a database? I hope you understand that a string can't ever magically turn into data.

Comment: @Neil yes I changed it from "var posSection = _UOW.Set<SysUsers>().Where(a => a.UserCode == userCode).Select(a=> new { PosSection = a.PosSection }).SingleOrDefault();" to above string! the problem is I need a string!

Comment: Look, you don't tell anything of your coding environment. That's why I asked the question above. We have no clue where to fit in a query string. Neither is it clear why it absolutely should be a string . You better pay close attention to comments when asking a question at Stack Overflow because they usually indicate where the question isn't clear and, hence, why it can't be answered.

Comment: @GertArnold it's a .net framwork and services base application, so I made a domain model and I have C# class (Application layer) dataTransferObject, Interface Layer(facad) and WebApi layer. and then Presentation layer that I uses services to read an write on DB. now in another service I wana read a data from another service which is reading data from sysUser table! I need a string to use it as a condition ! Is it why I need it!

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to write is string, not linq query. check the example below.

```
var query = from x in _sysusers
   where UserCode = userCode
   select x;

return query;
```

Comment: I wanna select PosSection so shuld I replace x with PosSection?!
            var query = from PosSection in SysUsers
                        where UserCode = userCode
                        select PosSection;

            return query;

Comment: I need a string value! can't I convert it to a value?

Comment: use `select x.PosSection`

Answer (score 0):

thanks my problem solved with these code, these code return a string which I need.

```
var posSectionTMP = _UOW.Set<SysUsers>().Where(a => a.UserCode == userCode).FirstOrDefault().PosSection;
```